# How to create multiple users at once?

Tags: plugins, users, user-registration

I'm working with a fresh wordpress database and I need to import +250 users at once from xlsx or csv, each user password has to be its name. It is possible to do this on Wordpress?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible if you have access to WP CLI:

`wp user import-csv`

https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/user/import-csv/